# Using variable to initialize an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-length-array

As C++ primer said, we can't use variable as the dimension of builtin array, so the following code did not work

```
int length = 3;
int array[length] = {0, 1, 2};
```

the error is

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

But why following code works?

```
int length = 3;
int array[length];
```

Comment: It's an extension by your compiler, it's not standard C++.

Comment: Don't compile it with GCC. It will stop working

Comment: Add `-pedantic-errors` to your compiler flags. Also throw in `-Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors` for good measure.

Comment: @StoryTeller I use clang++

Comment: @StoryTeller Wat? Stop working?

Comment: @hyde - To my knowledge, gcc was the only compiler with VLA support in C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#introduction

Comment: @hyde - Your point being?

Comment: @StoryTeller Just expanding on your *"To my knowledge, gcc was the only compiler..."*, for benefit of all readers.

Comment: NVM. They had to call it `cxx_runtime_array`... yuck

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension by your compiler called a [Variable Length Array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and is not in the C++ standard which means that this code can break at any moment you switch compilers or the compiler vendor decides to no longer support this feature. If you want a variable length array that does not depend on this extension but instead on the standard you should use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks. But now in my env it works, why the elements in the array is not 0?

Comment: @danche Because `array` is still uninitialized, it's not zero-initialized.

Comment: "or the compiler vendor decides to no longer support this feature", well, for extensions which are rather well established and documented, and have existed for longer than C++ has been standardized, I think that's just FUD. Features can't be retroactively removed from current versions. I'd be more worried about using latest C++ standard features and encountering a compiler bug, which will silently alter code behavior when it gets fixed in a minor version bump, or when compiling with different compiler...